# Authentication Hangs...Sometimes

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm not really sure how to ask this question, so I made a video. I've got a blazor web assembly app that I am creating and I am using the out of the box authentication (from the template). Most of the time (70%), authentication happens fast when I click the login button, other times it just hangs like you see in the video where the page is unresponsive and in the output console I see that lots of threads are exiting. To the best of my knowledge, I haven't modified anything about the authentication workflow.

I have no idea how to even begin trouble shooting this. Can anyone point me in the right direction or possibly know what might be causing this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TW7s1uCm3-o&list=WL&index=36&t=0s

Comment: Try running a release build (set dropdown to release) and run without debugger (ctrl + f5). See if the problem persists. It's almost certainly caused by something that's happening on your pc and isn't really a problem with the code.

Comment: Yeah ill bet is has something to do with it just not being in release mode. Ill bet once you deploy everything works as should. If anything try going to developer tools -> Application -> Clear storage and clear your site data. Even if it says 0 B I find this helps when I get hang ups in authentication while debugging.